# Hover an input element, which affects the placeholder

Tags: input, hover, placeholder

I have tried to change the placeholder color of the input element when you hover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `:hover` then `::placeholder` pseudoelement to change its color:

```
input:hover::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```